# Using jQuery to create two datepicker date-range instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I have two date range forms. Each form has 2 fields, a `from` and `to`. In the javascript I have created two instances of the date range datepicker but for some reason, in the second date range form, it doesn't quite work right.

The first form works perfectly. But when I select a date in the `from` box in the second form, 9th October for example it displays that in the `from` box. When I then click into the `to` field in the second form, the furthest date I can select is 9th Oct for some reason?

I have a JS Fiddle below so you can see what is going on. I've searched around but I cannot find any working examples of two date-range forms. I can find a lot of default date pickers, but they're of course not date ranges and written different and the usual problem with them is people using the same IDs, however mine are all different so I don't get it..

JS Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6jJ36/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/fxr5c/

Culprit was: `var option = this.id == "invfrom" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",` line of code in your old code you had id wrong i.e. `ivnfrom` which inversed the behavior.

Rest this should help your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
var dates = $("#from, #to").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

        var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings);
        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
var invdates = $("#invfrom, #invto").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

        var option = this.id == "invfrom" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
            instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
            selectedDate, instance.settings);
        invdates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't believe that! But thanks a lot for pointing it out, don't think I would have ever noticed it :)

Comment: @Nathan `:)` glad it helped bruv.